# ip2location query for a million+ records

Tags: database, perl

I have a subscription for a ip2location service which gives me a SQL table in this format

```
FromIP (int), ToIP(int), lat, long, city  etc etc
```

I would like to parse my access logs and categorize all users 
The access logs have IP address and userid ( say )

So I run a query like

```
select city from ip2location where FromIP <= $ipAsInt  AND ToIP => $ipAsInt
```

But this take too long for million+ records which I have to parse. I guess this must be a very common use of ip2location. Is it possible to optimize the structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest way was to lookup in sorted order of ips 
When I lookup an IP I select the last IP too

Like this

select city,ToIP from ip2location where FromIP <= $ipAsInt  AND ToIP => $ipAsInt

Now when I have to lookup the next address I dont query the table if the next ip is already less than the last $ToIP

For every 1000 lookups I query only around 80 times here.

Answer (score 2):

You can also write query like this

```
select city,ToIP from ip2location where ToIP >= $ipAsInt order by ToIP limit 1
```

This will be a lot faster than before.

Also you can index the ToIP column for improved performance.

And as [ip2location](http://www.ip2location.com/tutorials/redirect-web-visitors-by-country-using-php-and-mysql-database) suggests, you can create composite primary key of FromIP and ToIP using

```
ALTER TABLE ip2location ADD PRIMARY KEY(FromIP,ToIP);
```

Comment: does this work everytime correctly? To filter only ToIP field ?

Comment: Yes. Their data is structured in such a way that ToIP will suffice. For peace of mind you can also add `FromIP <= $ipAsInt` in where condition but wouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that you can do much, much better than `LIMIT 1`!

On the [ip2location website here](http://www.ip2location.com/tutorials/lookup-ip-proxy-optimization-mysql) it shows how using a subquery is **orders of magnitude faster**:

`SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM ip2location_db3 WHERE ip_to >= INET_ATON('8.8.8.8') LIMIT 1
) AS tmp WHERE ip_from <= INET_ATON('8.8.8.8')`

In my tests on my MacBook, different IP addresses took a different amount of time. The worst performing IP addresses had the following performance:

- 14s using `BETWEEN` without a `LIMIT 1`
- 300ms using `BETWEEN` with `LIMIT 1`
- 2ms using the sub-select above

That is 7000x faster!

Comment: Actually, you are confusing the IP2Proxy database with the IP2Location database. IP2Location databases contain all the IP addresses with no gaps so all you need is SELECT * FROM ip2location_db3 WHERE ip_to >= INET_ATON('8.8.8.8') LIMIT 1. For best performance, the ip_to field should be the primary key and no other indexes. On the other hand, the IP2Proxy databases do not contain all IP ranges so a sub-query is needed to optimise the query. In the case of IP2Proxy, your query will be the most optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your table is indexed on `FromIP` and `ToIP`.
Check your database, if it has features like complete in-memory tables for lookup.

Instead of sending a single statement for each IP you've got, you may want to load all IPs into another table and join the city to this table in one single SQL statement. That will be a lot faster than doing it one IP at a time.

Comment: I have seen many times that join queries end up much longer than sum of individual query times. Is there a thumb rule on when a group query can be used instead of individual query

Comment: Every single time. If your join on the database is slower than individual statements joined afterwards by another component, you need to optimize your database schema using indexes and proper queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you can code in perl you can  use Memoization http://perldoc.perl.org/Memoize.html
so that subsequent calls with the same IP would ***NOT*** be looked up in the DB.

Further optimization would be to query using the CLass C component of the IP to lookup if you are willing to lose some accuracy.

Also indexing on from_ip and to_ip as well as composite index would help.